# date4j not equals same day

Tags: java, datetime

I would like to point out an issue that might not be an issue after all but let me take you through my example..

i want to compare a date to another date without the  hours , minutes ,seconds etc.

the one date is now without the hh mm ss

```
  //Now Date
        DateTime now = DateTime.now(TimeZone.getDefault()).getStartOfDay();
```

so the other date comes from a feed where the format is "YYYY-MM-DD"

so i  create the date from this format
DateTime date_to_compare = new DateTime(date_strStartDate);

if the date_to_compare is the same day as today,

it doesn't equal the now date.

because date_to_compare has null values for hours, minutes,seconds etc.

so in the end  this never returns true even though its the same date.

```
if (now .gteq(date_to_compare ) && now .lteq(date_to_compare )   ){
   return true;
}
```

in order for this to work i came down to this idea.

```
DateTime date_to_compare = new DateTime(date_strStartDate+" 00:00:00.0000");
```

i explicitely add hours minutes, seconds to the date string in order to give the constructor some values.
then the previous statement returns true finally.

but this got me headache for  4days so a made this same issue to the date4j github channel.
https://github.com/IanDarwin/date4j/issues/1

and i am posting it here as well so it should save days from someone also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok mister John (https://github.com/johanley)

answered it by pointed me to an already defined function that doesn't take into account the TIME in the DateTime
Answer is also here
https://github.com/johanley/date4j/issues/4#issuecomment-204965719

> Hi,  In this case, you should use the 'isSameDayAs' method:
>
> http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/hirondelle/date4j/DateTime.html#isSameDayAs%28hirondelle.date4j.DateTime%29
>
> John